# Can I create a newspaper type document with photos and words and save directly on my iPad?

Tags: ipad

I have a 64GB iPad and would like to be able to create and then store directly onto my iPad a newspaper like document. So that I can have access to it without a wifi connection. Can this be done? I am new to Apple so still learning what it can do!

Comment: Are you looking at documents you create yourself from scratch or do you want to store web pages etc. for later (off-line) reading?

Comment: I want to creat my own from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

If you want any document you create to keep itself in pages, you can turn off iCloud for pages in the settings menu. https://i.stack.imgur.com/fKIck.jpg      When iCloud is enabled, it will allow access to your most recent documents.

If you have an external PDF viewer and want the document to be read only, you can export it as a PDF file then open it in an app like Readdle's PDF Expert or Adobe's Acrobat Reader.

Comment: Why do you recommend to turn off iCloud syncing for Pages?

Comment: @patrix it keeps everything on the device instead of uploading to iCloud. When documents are uploaded to iCloud, the device will delete the document from local storage, thus being available on *that* device all of the time.

Comment: Syncing via iCloud doesn't delete the local copy, at least this never happened to my documents so far

Comment: @patrix I have over 100 documents and they are taken off of my device if I leave them inactive for long enough. They automatically upload to icloud, then to save space, they remove themselves. I then have to wait for them to download.

Comment: Ah, ok, never had that problem before :-)

Comment: @patrix sometimes it happens. Especially with my 32GB.